# Create association lines with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics

I recently asked how to [Create association lines between characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139691/create-association-lines-between-characters), and I was open to all kinds of suggestions. Unfortunately, I failed to understand most of the answers given. I should perhaps have emphasized that the suggestions needed to be "dumbed down" with explanations/comments such that I would understand them (so that I can modify them and reuse them later). I liked the output from some `pstricks` derivatives such as `pst-asr` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139694/9077) and `pst-node` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139726/9077), but I don't really understand the code, and since the `pst-asr` and `pst-node` manuals are like mystery novels to me, I got stuck before I even started.

I will for that reason stick to `TikZ` for now, mainly because the manual is more or less comprehensible to me, and I've used `TikZ` a little bit before.

Below is a MWE of what I have come up with, based on Alan Munn's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139694/9077). There are a few problems there already:

1. The space between the characters in the word 'asta' is uneven. I'd prefer the same distance between characters as when a word is typed in normal text.
2. The two lines in the word 'asta' are of unequal length. They should be the same length.
3. The two lines in the word 'asta' don't join smoothly. This is addressed on page 140 in the `TikZ` manual, but there is no explanation, it just says "appreciate the difference" (which I do).
4. The H in the word 'asta' should be in between the two anchors, not directly above the second anchor.

If some of these issues cannot be resolved with `TikZ`, I'd be happy to go back to something like `pst-asr` or `pst-node` instead. If so, I should insist this time that the code is explained, otherwise it will not be worth your effort. Since I cannot understand the manuals for `pst-asr` or `pst-node`, I need to rely on explanations from you guys ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (mymatrix) % assign matrix name in ()
        [
            matrix of nodes,
            nodes = {inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 1pt}
            % 'inner sep' sets the space around the node, i.e. between nodes
            % 'outer sep' sets the space between the node and the anchor that lines will be drawn from/to
        ]
    % create matrix of nodes: each node has the name 'matrix name'-'row number'-'column number'
    {
        & H &\\
        [2ex] % distance between rows
        a & s & a\\
    };
    \draw (mymatrix-1-2) -- (mymatrix-2-2); % draw line (--) from row1/column2 to row2/column2
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (mymatrix2)
        [
            matrix of nodes,
            nodes = {inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 1pt}
        ]
    {
        & & H &\\
        [2ex]
        a & s & t & a\\
    };
    \draw (mymatrix2-1-3.south) -- (mymatrix2-2-2.north);
     % south anchor = in the middle at the bottom of the node
     % north anchor = in the middle at the top of the node
    \draw (mymatrix2-1-3) -- (mymatrix2-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: Alenanno's suggestion**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        every node/.style = % set style of all nodes
            {
                minimum height = 4mm, % set minimum height of node (the higher, the further away from the node the lines will be drawn)
                text height = 1mm, % set height of text in node? How can the text be 1mm high?
                text depth = 0ex % depth?? What does this do?
            },
        level 1/.style = % set style for the highest level in the tree
            {
                level distance = 7mm, % set distance between levels in the tree
                sibling distance = 2mm % set distance between nodes within a level
            },
        edge from parent/.style = % set style for the connection between parents and children???
            {
                draw,
                edge from parent path = % set the edges for parent node and child node
                    {(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)} % south/north = in the middle at the bottom/top of the node
            },
        abs/.style = % ??
            {edge from parent/.style = {draw = none}} % ??
    ]

\node{H} % the text of parent node
    child[abs]  {node{a}}
    child       {node{s}} 
    child[abs]  {node{a}}
;

\node[xshift = 2cm]{H} % shift all points in this node on the x-axis (to avoid pictures to overlap)
    child[abs]  {node{a}}
    child       {node{s}} 
    child       {node{t}}
    child[abs]  {node{a}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Won't this always put `H` in the middle of the word? What if I want `H` to branch off only to the first two characters in the word or something like that?

Comment: Since what `pst-asr` is designed specifically for the task you require, it might be worthwhile to figure it out. I could help explain the manual better if I have some idea about what sorts of representations you are likely to be drawing (beyond the examples in your original question.) I was in a bit of a rush when I posted my original answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn At the moment I just need to draw representations like those in my question, and I'm not sure if ``pst-asr`` as such is better suited for that than ``TikZ``. That depends in part on whether the problems I raise in my question here can be fixed with ``TikZ``. If not, I actually like the output of ``pst-node`` better ...

Comment: @Sverre The same as Alan from me. I can explain the `pst-asr` code, I used it extensively for my ResMA thesis and I have plenty of time (for now). I didn't really get why you need the ph tier characters to be spaced as normal text... You want them integrated in the running text?

Comment: @AlanMunn I had some questions to the ``pst-asr`` code in the edit to my original question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139691/create-association-lines-between-characters. Could you have a look at that?
@Stefano The only reason I wanted the characters on the ph tier to be spaced as normal text is because that's what the original I am going to copy the example from does ... (and no, I intend to include them as figures or ``gb4e`` examples).

Comment: @Sverre `syB` set the baseline of the syllable tier 2em above the baseline of the base tier (which is the timing tier); you don't need to restate that afterwards (so `\asr[syB=2m]` is redundant). As for sysym I answered to your question in a comment to my answer (I suppose).

Answer (score 2):

## Tikz trees

This is the updated solution with Tikz. I managed to solve a particular problem that previously made me choose regular trees, which is that the ***t*** from *"asta"* created problems of alignment with the other letters.

The **abs** style says `abs/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=none}}`.

Basically every child node with this option will not show the edge from its parent. As you can see it says `draw=none` and below, whenever you see `child[abs]`, the line does not appear for that child node.

So: write `child[abs]` where you don't want the lines to appear, and leave it without `[abs]` where you want the lines to appear.

By the way, **abs** is just short for **absent**. I just chose a word for that, but you can write whatever as keyword, except maybe commands that already exist with Latex that might create issues (it will throw an error when that happens I think).

[image: tikz trees image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum height=4mm,text height=1mm,text depth=0ex},
    level 1/.style={level distance=9mm,sibling distance=2mm},
    edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
    abs/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=none}}
]

\node {H}
child[abs] { node {a}}
child { node {s}} 
child[abs] { node {a}}
;

\node[xshift=2cm] {H}
child[abs] { node {a}}
child { node {s}} 
child { node {t}}
child[abs] { node {a}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

## Regular trees

I tried a different approach and used Syntax trees. If you do a simple tree, the lines from the parent node to its children are all of equal length. I reduced the spacing between the letters, and you could change that code to make it look better, but I don't know if something is going to break and look awful.

I considered using Tikz trees but you need to type more code (let me know if you prefer that approach).

This is what it looks like with regular trees:

[image: regular trees image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}    
    \qtreecenterfalse

    \Tree [.\raisebox{-.3cm}{H} !\qsetw{-1mm} a !\qsetw{-1mm} s !\qsetw{-1mm} a ] \hskip .5cm
    \Tree [.\raisebox{-.3cm}{H} !\qsetw{-1mm} a !\qsetw{-1mm} s !\qsetw{-1mm} t !\qsetw{-1mm} a ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the best approach for @Sverre, but minimally you would be better off with `tikz-qtree` or better yet the `forest` package (which specializes in compact trees) if you were to do this using a tree package.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the feedback. Do you think this is not a good approach in general or for this case? And why? I'll try to work on some Tikz tree. :)

Comment: There are two possible issues I see. One is keeping the characters close together, which will be a problem with any tree package. Second is that some of the structures needed may end up not being trees but graphs in which case a tree package can become more of a hindrance.

Comment: One advantage is that the H in 'asta' ends up 'between' two characters. But do all the nodes in the tree have to branch up? If so, that's clearly not what I am after.

Comment: @AlanMunn I updated the answer with Tikz trees. I had a problem with it earlier, that's why I chose not to use it. I solved it now. :)

Comment: @Sverre I replicated the image that you showed in your question. Did you want some edges to not be drawn? Let me know if that is what you were after.

Comment: @Alenanno Your TikZ solution does look pretty good, I must say. I'll play with it and see if I can understand it! :)

Comment: @Alenanno I've included a MWE based on your suggestion. I don't understand everything. Please have a look :)

Comment: @Sverre Sorry, I was not here. Since you seem to have trouble understanding how the lines work, I added something about that. Read from the second paragraph of my answer, where it says *"The **abs** style..."*. The following 4 paragraphs will explain how you can decide what lines to draw. :)

Comment: @Alenanno I see. The ``abs`` confused me, because ``abs`` is already a function explained in the ``TikZ`` manual. I noticed when swapping around the ``[abs]`` in the first word that the ``H`` node indeed always appears in the middle of the word, as I expected. That would not be what I want. Any way to set where the mother node appears?

Comment: @Sverre Not that I'm aware of at the moment, but this was not something you originally requested so I thought that you wanted it at the center. I am looking into it, but I am not sure about how to do it.